# Visual Express installation aborted at KB2999226 update

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have windows 8.1 installed on my computer. I tried to install Visual Express 2015 on it and the installation get aborted when it tries to install `KB2999226` update.

Then I tried to install that update manually. But it says that the update is not applicable to my computer.

Why is this? Does that `KB2999226` update needs any other update to to be installed beforehand?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio Express do you have installed precisely.  Include which update(s) you have installed.  "and the installation get aborted" what error code do you receive?  I ask this because you say you have Express except, that was discontinued, and there is only Community now on the free side.

Answer (score 1):

#### Does the KB2999226 update need any other update to to be installed beforehand?

> **Prerequisites**
>
> To install this update, you must have [April 2014 update rollup for
>   Windows RT 8.1, Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2 (2919355)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355)
>   installed in Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2. Or, install
>   [Service Pack 1 for Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976932). Or,
>   install [Service Pack 2 for Windows Vista and for Windows Server
>   2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948465).

Source [KB2999226 - Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give you a background on Universal CRT this would help you in understanding as to why the system should be updated before installing `vc_redist.x64.exe`.

A large portion of the C-runtime moved into the OS in Windows 10 (`ucrtbase.dll`) and is serviced just like any other OS DLL (e.g. `kernel32.dll`). It is no longer serviced by Visual Studio directly. MSU packages are the file type for Windows Updates.

In order to get the Windows 10 Universal CRT to earlier OSes, Windows Update packages were created to bring this OS component downlevel. `KB2999226` brings the Windows 10 RTM Universal CRT to downlevel platforms (Windows Vista through Windows 8.1). `KB3118401` brings Windows 10 November Update to the Universal CRT to downlevel platforms.

Windows XP (latest SP) is an exception here. Windows Servicing does not provide downlevel packages for that OS, so Visual Studio (Visual C++) provides a mechanism to install the UCRT into `System32` via the VCRedist and MSMs.

---

1. The Windows Universal Runtime is included in the VC Redist exe package as it has dependency on the Windows Universal Runtime (`KB2999226`).

   Windows 10 is the only OS that ships the UCRT in-box.  All prior OSes obtain the UCRT via Windows Update only. This applies to all Vista → 8.1 and associated Server SKUs.

   For Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 the Windows Universal Runtime must be installed via `KB2999226`. However it has a prerequisite update `KB2919355` which contains updates that facilitate installing the `KB2999226` package.

---

2. Why does KB2999226 not always install when the runtime is installed from the redistributable?  What could prevent `KB2999226` from installing as part of the runtime?

   The UCRT MSU included in the VCRedist is installed by making a call into the Windows Update service and the KB can fail to install based upon Windows Update service activity/state:

   - If the machine has not updated to the required servicing baseline, the UCRT MSU will be viewed as being “Not Applicable”.

     Ensure `KB2919355` is installed. Also, there were known issues with `KB2919355`  so before this the following hotfix should be installed: `KB2939087`, `KB2975061`.
   - If the Windows Update service is installing other updates when the VCRedist installs, you can either see long delays or errors indicating the machine is busy.

     This one can be resolved by waiting and trying again later (which may be why installing via Windows Update UI at a later time succeeds).
   - If the Windows Update service is in a non-ready state, you can see errors reflecting that.

     We recently investigated a failure with an error code indicating the WUSA service was shutting down.

---

3. To identify if the prerequisite `KB2919355` is installed there are 2 options:

   Registry key:

   64bit hive

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.14
   CurrentState = 112
   ```

   32bit hive

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\[WOW6432Node\]Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.1.14
   CurrentState = 112
   ```

   Or check the file version of:

   ```
   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wuaueng.dll
   C:\Windows\System32\wuaueng.dll
   ```

   `7.9.9600.17031`  or later.

Comment: Why are you posting identical answers to multiple question? The correct thing to do is to post a single answer (if appropriate) and flag the other questions as duplicates.

Comment: `CurrentState = 112` _and_ `wuaueng.dll = 7.9.9600.17404` but `KB2999226` still won't install.